# AngularJS route renaming

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I have an angular app that lives on `mysite.com/angularapp` and there is no need for a route provider. When I load the page, the URL changes to `mysite.com/angularapp#/angularapp`. I'd like the URL to not include the hash. I could manually clear this with `window.location.hash` but I would like it disabled so the URL doesn't flicker with the hashed URL from the beginning . I also can't use `html5mode` ([source](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location#hashbangandhtml5modes)) because there are still many links which are bound to server-side requests (so I can't simply re-route my entire app to work as a single-page app). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that this is a [known bug in Angular 1.1.5](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/fPCXGOPuK0o) (which I was using). Downgrading to 1.1.4 will remove this problem.